# Tools to check whether an executable has SIMD instructions in it?

Tags: disassembly

Theoretically we can analysis a binary executable/library to see whether it contains any SSE and/or AVX opcode. However, it may be a bit tedious and error-prone. Are there any tools I can use to get a quick answer without dissembling the binary myself?

Note: This approach will probably fail to catch dynamically generated opcode (e.g. from JIT-compilers, interpreters, Java/.Net virtual machines) but that's fine for me. I'm mostly dealing with "normal" programs written in C/C++.

Comment: Great question and I'm surprised there is no answer for it yet. It shouldn't be hard to make a tool to inspect binaries and tabulate instructions.